Remote Desktop (xrdp) does not work on Ubuntu 22.04 using GNOME desktop
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS. desktop is GNOME 42.9.
I installed xrdp using sudo apt install xrdp command. Firewall is not turned on because sudo ufw status command returns Status: inactive. xrdp is added into ssl-cert group using sudo adduser xrdp ssl-cert command, and XRDP service is restarted. Connection to the Ubuntu server has no problem. I can't upgrade to 24.04 and reboot.
When I tried to connect to the Remote Desktop on Windows using Xorg session type, I got an empty screen, nothing but all cyan or black color.
Below is the /var/log/xrdp-sesman.log file:
[20241011-02:00:15] [INFO ] starting xrdp-sesman with pid 999313
[20241011-02:00:48] [INFO ] Socket 8: AF_INET6 connection received from ::1 port 47050
[20241011-02:00:48] [INFO ] Terminal Server Users group is disabled, allowing authentication
[20241011-02:00:48] [INFO ] ++ created session (access granted): username hzhou11, ip ::ffff:172.27.16.37:62953 - socket: 12
[20241011-02:00:48] [INFO ] starting Xorg session...
[20241011-02:00:48] [INFO ] Found X server running at /tmp/.X11-unix/X10
[20241011-02:00:48] [ERROR] g_tcp_bind(9, 6011) failed bind IPv6 (errno=98) and IPv4 (errno=22).
[20241011-02:00:48] [INFO ] Found X server running at 6011
[20241011-02:00:48] [INFO ] Found X server running at /tmp/.X11-unix/X12
[20241011-02:00:48] [INFO ] Found X server running at /tmp/.X11-unix/X13
[20241011-02:00:48] [INFO ] Starting session: session_pid 1000436, display :14.0, width 3840, height 2160, bpp 24, client ip ::ffff:172.27.16.37:62953 - socket: 12, user name ...
[20241011-02:00:48] [ERROR] sesman_data_in: scp_process_msg failed
[20241011-02:00:48] [INFO ] [session start] (display 14): calling auth_start_session from pid 1000436
[20241011-02:00:48] [ERROR] sesman_main_loop: trans_check_wait_objs failed, removing trans
[20241011-02:00:48] [INFO ] Starting X server on display 14: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg :14 -auth .Xauthority -config xrdp/xorg.conf -noreset -nolisten tcp -logfile .xorgxrdp.%s.log
[20241011-02:00:48] [INFO ] Found X server running at /tmp/.X11-unix/X14
[20241011-02:00:48] [INFO ] Found X server running at /tmp/.X11-unix/X14
[20241011-02:00:48] [INFO ] Found X server running at /tmp/.X11-unix/X14
[20241011-02:00:48] [INFO ] Starting the default window manager on display 14: /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
[20241011-02:00:48] [INFO ] Session started successfully for user ... on display 14
[20241011-02:00:48] [INFO ] Starting the xrdp channel server for display 14
[20241011-02:00:48] [INFO ] Session in progress on display 14, waiting until the window manager (pid 1000437) exits to end the session

I have searched Internet for quite a while but got no solution for me. How to fix this? Thanks.
